# Symmetry breaking in 1D wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetry, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^{2} \rho}{\partial t^{2}}-c_{s}^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\left(\rho+\nu \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}\right)=0 \tag{1}
$$ 
with boundary conditions

$$\left.\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0, L}=f(t)$$

I rewrite the variable $\rho$ as

$$\rho(x, t)=u(x, t)+\boxed{x f(t)} \tag{2}$$

in order to rewrite the boundary conditions as homogeneous and then solve the corresponding PDE with the method of eigenfunctions.

The problem is: equation 1 and its BCs clearly have Mirror symmetry in space (that is: I can swap the boundary condition is $x=0$ and in $x=L$ without changing anything in the PDE). The solution (eq. 2) is composed of two terms: the first one is linear in space (variable $x$), therefore it does not respect mirror symmetry anymore.

More in detail, I expect the solution to be even with respect to the axis at $x=L/2$. Equation 2 is composed by two terms: $u(x,t)$ respects the symmetry (it comes down from the solution of the modified PDE), therefore I expect $xf(t)$ to respect the same symmetry, but it doesn't.

How is that possible?

---

The new boundary conditions for the new functions $u(x,t)$ are

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0, L}=0$$

And the new PDE is

$$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\left(c_{s}^{2} u+\nu \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)=-x \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial t^{2}}$$

The solution $u(x,t)$ (not shown, becuse it is not simple and not useful for this question) is symmetrical with respect to the center of the domain $(0, L)$.

Comment: In general, if you translate something do you expect it to have the same reflection symmetry as the original location?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am not sure I am understanding your comment correctly. It does not seem to be a problem of the selected reference frame. The function $F(x)=mx + q$ is not an even function whatever is the value of $q$.

Comment: But it can be an odd function if you choose $q$ correctly. Symmetry is not preserved by translation. In this case this is a translation in your function space.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I know that symmetry is not preserved by translation, I could restate my question rewriting the BCs in $x=\pm L/2$ and it won't change anything. An odd function won't respect the mirror symmetry of the PDE, I expect the solution to be even with respect to the axis at $x=L/2$. Equation 2 is not.

Comment: You are talking about translations in your $domain$. The transformation $\rho = u + xf$ is a translation in your $function \hspace{2 pt}space$. When I say the symmetry isn't preserved I mean we have left the set of functions that had the symmetry. And you shouldn't expect $u$ to have the symmetry. The only way that $\rho$ could be a sum of those two objects and still have the symmetry is if both $u$ and $xf(t)$ didn't have the symmetry in just the right way to cancel out the asymmetry.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I got your point now. Still, I don't expect $u$ to have the symmetry. I expect $\rho$ to have the symmetry and I don't see why It should not have it, being the solution of a symmetrical PDE (whatever is the method I used to find the solution). Now, $\rho$ can be written as a sum of two terms, namely $u$ and $xf$. $u$ happens to have the symmetry (I don't expect it to have it, it just has it. It comes down from the calculations that I did not provide because they are not important for the question), therefore $xf$ should be symmetrical too.

Comment: You have the deduction backwards. $u$ does not have symmetry while $\rho$ does. The reason is if we want to conclude the solution to a pde has a symmetry, both the equation and the boundary condition must have that symmetry. While the boundary conditions for both $\rho$ and $u$ have that symmetry, the pde for $\rho$ is symmetric while the pde for $u$ is not.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I do agree that the PDE for $u$ is not symmetrical, while the PDE for $\rho$ is symmetrical. Therefore, I expect the solution $\rho$ to respect the same symmetry, while $u$ to not respect it. Though, from what I see, $u$ respects the symmetry of the PDE for $\rho$ (I have no idea why) and $\rho$ is not symmetrical because of the term $xf$. Could you please elaborate why I am wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons as to why the second equation doesn't have the symmetry that you want.

The first is that you are only considering the symmetry in the variable $x$, that is
$$ x \rightarrow L - x$$
but this symmetry changes the sign of first order derivatives, so the boundary conditions are not preserved,
$$ \partial_x \rho = f(t) \rightarrow - \partial_x \rho = f(t)$$
so to have an actual symmetry we have to either change the sign of $f$ or $\rho$, lets choose $\rho$ for the moment.$$ x \rightarrow L - x, \rho \rightarrow -\rho$$
this implies in particular, thet if the initial conditions satisfy this symmetry, that is
$$\rho_0(x) =  - \rho_0(L - x)$$
$$\rho_{t0}(x) = - \rho_{t0}(L - x)$$
then the solution also has this symmetry ( you can prove this by the uniqueness of the solution).

The second reason is that you broke the symmetry when defining $u$ by introducing the function $x$ which is not symmetric. If we use the antisymmetric function $(x - \frac L2)$,
$$ \rho = u + \left(x - \frac L2\right)f$$
then the equation for $u$,
$$\partial_{tt} \rho - \partial_{xx}(c_s u + \nu \partial_t u) = - \left(x - \frac L 2\right) \partial_{tt} f$$
is invariant to the symmetry 
$$ x \rightarrow L - x, \rho \rightarrow -\rho$$
because the change in sign from the antisymmetric function $(x - L/2)$ cancels with the change in sign of $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am afraid my question was not clear enough. I was not asking why the second PDE is not symmetrical, but why the **solution** $\rho(x,t)$ of the **first** PDE (equation tagged as number 2) is not symmetrical. Indeed the linear part $xf$ of eq. 2 is not even with respect to the central axis at $L/2$, even if I use the function $(x-L/2)$ as you suggest. I do expect $\rho(x,t)$ to be even with respect to the center of the domain $(0, L)$ because I can reflect the BCs without changing the formulation of the PDE.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino That is what I explained at the first part, you have to consider the change in sign in either $\rho$ or $f$ in order to preserve the boundary conditions. Because usually f is consider fixed, maybe it is better to consider the change in sign in $\rho$ instead. That is why you obtain odd (w/r to $L/2$) functions instead of even functions. I modified the answer a little bit to try to explain it more clearly.